# Is there an async FUSE filesystem for replication?

Tags: replication, mirror, fuse

I have a low-power VIA x86 PC with one SATA port. I want to backup special files (ie: /var) from the SATA drive on this port onto a USB flash disk, but I don't want a RAID1 or fully-synchronous solution for performance reasons.

It is acceptable that data isn't entirely 100% durable/reliable, but I am looking for something more elegant than rsync-ing every 5minutes in crontab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the lsyncd tool to automate your rsyncs - that uses the filesystem notifier to re-run rsyncs as files change.

Apart from that the other replication options are a lot more heavy-weight, using gluster backed onto both your "real" location and your "backup" would give you mirroring but the extra overhead is noticeable.

Comment: What is the "fsync tool"?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/

Comment: OP wants to use [_FUSE_](https://github.com/immobiliare/sfs) and avoid using _rsync_, but answer is about automating _rsync_, again. And, is it supposed that _rsync_ is [lightweight](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/speed-up-rsync-when-migrating-a-linux-server-from-the-command-line/) and its overhead is not noticeable?..

Comment: Found this answer when looking for a FUSE replicator - I'd already looked at lsyncd but discovered I would need to add around 6Gb of RAM just to hold the kernel inotify data (and goodness only knows what the performance would be like). I*n my case I'm dealing with a *lot* of files though.

Comment: ChironFS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiron_FS (possibly in debian repo?)

sfs https://github.com/immobiliare/sfs

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @symcbean, ChironFS is a FUSE based filesystem that replicates files to two or more filesystems. It takes almost no configuration from the command line. It's latest version is at https://github.com/tweksteen/chironfs .